# Local database file connection error on another pc

Tags: vb.net

I've a connection string in my project for single mdf file as:

```
Private conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|datadirectory|BillAdjustment.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
Private cmd As New SqlCommand
```

This connection works perfect on my pc but don't work on another pc and gets error:

```
A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
```

My database installs in `appdata` folder.
is there any solution?

Comment: Did you  include sql server in the prerequisites before building or is there sql express or anything similar installed on thisother pc? Maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321508/publish-a-project-with-local-database/28321997#28321997

Comment: no i didn't, i don't know how to include. please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including SQL Server in the prerequisites before building.

In Solution Explorer:

**Rightclick your project** -> **Properties** -> **Publish** -> **Prerequisites**

In the Prerequisites window **check SQL Server Express LocalDB** (or whatever you are using):

[image]

This will forward the user to SQL Server download and installation during the installation of your application.