# Can i make sql Database part of c# Project

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I have made a sample c# application (First project ive done) Its quite a simple application which uses a database to store data and edit data.

The problem i am having is the program works perfectly fine on my computer but if i publish the application and put it on another computer it cannot use the database as it is not part of the project.

I used connection string

```
private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"C:\\Users\\Ryan\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\youtubeLoginTut\\youtubeLoginTut\\data.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
```

Which is obviously the path to the database on my computer and will not be the same on the next computer. Is there anyway i could include the database in the package so its referenced from where ever the application sits.

Ive tried shortening the path to for example ..\data.mdf but to no avail and i cant find anything on google so im all out of ideas.

Go easy im very new to c#

Cheers
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to get the location of your project in every computer : (inside the bin/debug/)

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory //example : C:/Users/Ryan/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Youtubetut/bin/debug
```

you just need add the location of the database inside of the project's folder to this path. `path` will replace your "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\youtubeLoginTut" and make sure to move your database inside the debug folder.

Comment: Right i got this working perfect, Now what i need is for the database to actaully be included when i publish, It works perfectly fine in the microsoft visual studio but when i publish and run the app the database isnt there, I have moved the database over to where the exe is and it works but is there anyway i can get it so it does this automatically ? Cheers

Comment: I think you can find what you are looking here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321508/publish-a-project-with-local-database

Comment: Thankyou so much, Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Afeter publiching your database with your project you get the Installtion Path From  Deployment byuse :

```
string sourcePath =System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
sourcePath =sourcePath +"\data.mdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple application you can try to use embeded DB like [SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). I use it in my application and it works fine.

Comment: Could you explain how i would go about this please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SQLite, let's go step by step.

1. download the dynamic library [System.Data.SQLite.dll](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) for your version of the .NET Framework
2. link System.Data.SQLite.dll to your project
3. write a code something like this

Create a table

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Version=3;New=True;", "./db/mydatabase.sdb"));
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE Books (BookId int, BookName varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (BookId));";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Read the data

```
using(SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Version=3;New=False;", "./db/mydatabase.sdb")) {
   con.Open();
   using (SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
   {
      cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT BookName FROM Books WHERE BookId=1 LIMIT 1;";
      using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
         if (reader.HasRows && reader.Read()) {
            oResult = Convert.ToString(reader["BookName"]);
         }
         reader.Close();
      }
   }
   con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much this is perfect for my project. :)