# How do I publish a windows forms application in visual studio 2017 with a localDB?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2017, local-database

I can't seem to find a simple answer to this on google. 
I need to create an executable of my application, so that it can easily be opened and used. The application has a database in it, which is made within the same solution in visual studio. I have tried to simply publish the application, but then the database doesn't seem to work as it immediately shows exeptions every time it needs the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deploy+C%23+app+with+sql+express

Comment: while you can make LocalDB work, it is not intended for production use. It is a development tool. You still need it installed and the proper instance name/version created.

Comment: This is for school, and one of the requirements is that the database is build within the C# project. (first time I worked with databases)

Comment: Please indicate the exception you're generating. This may make it easier to diagnose the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work with the answer of the question in this link:
[publish a project with local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321508/publish-a-project-with-local-database#28321997)